Unexpected msgpack code 164 (fixstr) encountered
Раньше, между клиентом и сервером летал JSON.
Решил поменять на msgpack и на сервере начала вылетать ошибка вида:
Unexpected msgpack code 164 (fixstr) encountered.

Сам по себе объект с большим числом полей различных типов.
Можно как-то понять, на каком именно поле вылетает ошибка не сравнивая объекты друг напротив друга?
